# Symfony2 go to anchor from controller directly

Tags: php, symfony, anchor

Searched through SO but solutions involves redirects, which I cannot do (because I need to keep the submitted form values for the action intact).

Now I have this action.

```
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function someAction() {
    // ...
    return array(
        'param' => $whatever,
        'anchor' => 'someAnchor'
    );     
}
```

How do you let this action go to `someAnchor` directly, i.e. instead of going to http://example.com/some/route/some, it goes to http://example.com/some/route/some#someAnchor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to particular anchor can be done through
1) HTTP header - Location
2) Anchor tag
2) JavaScript

For your case, you are left with last option.

**Sol**
After page load, change the URL with anchor.